# (Foundation 5) Are floating attributes without = signs in HTML tags same as with equals sign?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation-5

Are the following treated the same in foundation 5?

`<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">`

`<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="" role="navigation">`

I am asking because I am using Scala to produce HTML from the backend. I am not sure if I can use Scala to produce HTML like this
`<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">`

This all kind of stems me looking at this example and seeing that data-topbar doesn't have an ="stuff" 
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

Comment: why do you ask? what happened to make you ask this? or what are you trying to do?

Comment: I added some background, thanks

Comment: What happens when you try it? Does it work or not? I assume from my experience that it'll work just fine with `data-topbar=""`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom attribute, so are you are really saying is it's empty by either doing

```
data-topbar
```

or

```
 data-topbar=
```

They are most generally used to for javascript to get values from. Like you could use jquery to do something like

```
$(".top-bar").attr("data-topbar");
```

You can checkout more on custom attributes here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: I need to know if in Foundation 5, the following are treated the same: data-topbar    and   data-topbar=""    as in when your webpage loads, is it functionally equivalent

Comment: @PhilipNguyen yes it's just looking on the document for that custom attribute